# What performance counter type to use?

Tags: c#, performancecounter

We do use zip compression in our application quite extensively. I need to measure performance of different zip compressors using real life data (synthetic tests that we performed appear to be not very precise) compressed/uncompressed inside the application.

There is a utility method doing compression/decompression on demand, so I need to measure its performance and get some average. This average is basically an average rate (total number of bytes compressed divided by total time spent).

I played with different types of performance counters and I'm a little confused by the results.

What type of counter is the most appropriate in my case? Would it be RateOfCountsPerSecond64 or AverageCount64? Again, I don't need to change counter value when the system is idle; average should stay the same. Time elapsed while the system is idle doesn't count as well.

Comment: The _total number of bytes compressed divided by total time spent_ doesn't seem a sensitive approach. You are mixing-up two dimensions and ending with a non-representative number. What if the method is VERY fast, but doesn't compress anything?

Comment: I will have to measure compression ratio (how well particular zipper compresses data) separately, I agree (it should also be measured as average value for different operations performed by the app). But in this particular situation, how would you suggest to calculate compression rate then?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you're going to directly find a performance counter that indicates the overall score for any given compressor/decompressor.

As belisarius commented, you have at least two independent variables that contribute to the score:

- compression ratio
- time spent

And there may be others:

- size of input file
- whether the compression algorithm is well suited for the given input data (for example, some compression techniques work better depending on whether the input file is text, graphics, video, etc.)

And so on. If I were you, I would measure the raw values of each independent variable with its own performance counter, or even multiple counters.

Then, use the Performance Monitor Data Collector to collect logs of these counters, and crunch them later, where you can weight dimensions to suit your analysis (figure out whether it matters more to have faster compression or a higher compression ratio, and discard edge cases, etc.).

Also, the following codeproject.com article has a nice breakdown of different counters and useful examples of what they would measure. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42001/NET-Best-Practice-No-3-Using-performance-counters